# PHP can't find variable

Tags: php

So Im relatively new to PHP from ASP. And After converting alot of ASP code into PHP I have come across a problem where my PHP code seems unable to find the hidden variable I have set. It worked fine in ASP and was just wondering the best way to resolve this.

Start of the Form:

```
<form name="LogIn" action="login.php" method="post">
                    <td bgColor=#ffffff>
                        <table align="center" cellSpacing="2" cellPadding="2" border="0">
                            <tr>
                                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                <td align="right"><font color="#4d71a1">User name:</font>&nbsp;</td>
                                <td><input name="UserName" size="25" type="Text" autocomplete="OFF"></td>
                                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                <td align="right"><font color="#4d71a1">Password:</font>&nbsp;</td>
                                <td><input name="Password" size="25" type="Password" autocomplete="OFF"></td>
                                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                            </tr>
```

PHP script:

```
<? 
if ($_POST["BtnPress"]=="Pressed")
{

if ($_POST["Username"]=="*****" && $_POST["password"]=="*********")
{

$_SESSION['AdminID']="1";
header("Location: "."index.php");
}
  else
{

print "<font color=#ff0000>Sorry you cannot access this part of the site.</font>";
} 

} 
?>
```

then the rest of the form:

```
<tr>
                                <td align="center" colspan="4">
                                    <input type="hidden" name="BtnPress" value="Pressed">
                                    <input type="Submit" value="Log In" class="mybutton" onclick="return CheckForm();">
                                </td>   
                            </tr>
                        </table>


                    </td>
                </form>
```

The PHP seems unable to find the variable BtnPress, its a similar problem throughout alot of my translated ASP to PHP script. Sorry if it is a simple solution but can anyone tell me where I am going wrong?

Comment: `var_dump` helps see the contents of variables. do a `var_dump($_POST);` to see what the page is actually recieving.

Comment: Its just a javascript validation script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use a hidden input to test if a form is submitted.

use:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
  // processing of $_POST
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You have `name="Password"` and `$_POST["password"]`

`Password` != `password`

Watch your case.

---

```
<form name="LogIn" action="login.php" method="post">
                    <td bgColor=#ffffff>
```

That is invalid HTML. A `<td>` element cannot be a child element of a `<form>`. Browsers are likely to error recover in ways that break your HTML (e.g. by moving the form, but not its contents, outside the table). Do [use a validator](http://validator.w3.org/).

---

And stuff that isn't likely to be the cause of the problem, but is likely to be the cause of other problems.

- Don't use [layout tables](http://www.hotdesign.com/seybold/everything.html)
- Do use [the label element](http://www.webbie.org.uk/usingthelabelelement.htm)
- Do use CSS for presentation (you can style your label elements instead of using the obsolete `font` element

Answer (score 0):

The name of the submit button should be "BtnPressed" not the hidden field.
What I would do would be to set the form action to ?id=submit or something like that, and then check "if $_GET['id'] == "submit" then process data.

```
<form action="login.php?do=submit">

....  <input ..... 

</form>
<?php
if($_GET['do'] == "submit"){

//process data

} ?>
```